# How to make Energy Saver Schedule to Shutdown when logged out

Tags: shutdown, macos, energy

I have an iMac with the Energy Saver schedule to turn off at a specific time and then restart in the morning. It does not work if I am logged out. How do I make it work if no one is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pmset repeat` commands in Terminal to accomplish this:

`pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 11:00:00` will shutdown at 11AM.

`pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU 23:00:00` will boot (or wake from sleep) at 11PM.